# virtualbox stopped sharing mouse and clipboard between host OS and VM

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, centos, yum

I have VirtualBox 4.3.28 installed on Windows, with CentOS installed in a VM inside VirtualBox. For some time, I have been able to share the mouse and the clipboard between the host OS and the VM OS. This has been very convenient. **However recently this sharing ability stopped working. How can I get it back?**

Is there a `yum` command I can run in the VM OS' terminal to accomplish this? I recently typed `yum update` in CentOS and am not sure if that global update mixed anything up.

As per @heavyd's suggestion, I checked the `devices` menu to confirm that both `shared clipboard` and `drag n drop` are set to `bidirectional`. I could not find an `input` menu.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the "Input" and "Devices" menus?

Comment: @heavyd not sure how to do that.  do you have a link?

Comment: The menus are on the VM window.  Here's a screenshot:  https://www.virtualbox.org/attachment/wiki/Screenshots/Ubuntu_14.04_on_Windows_7.png

Comment: @heavyd Please see screen shot I just added to my OP.

Comment: Will you also add your VirtualBox version.  It looks like its not the current version, 5.0.

Comment: @heavyd  version 4.3.28